# Failed to get user's current position using google map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display map with current location using google map API using java script but unable to fetch the user's current location.I am explaining my code below.

```
window.onload = function () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
        } else {
            alert("Geo Location is not supported on your current browser!");
        }
        function success(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;
            var city = position.coords.locality;
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
            var myOptions = {
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                title: "lat: " + lat + " long: " + long + "city:" + city
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>User Address</b><br/> Latitude:" + lat + "<br /> Longitude:" + long + "<br /> City:"+city+"" });
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    }
```

And also i am using the below script links.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyBIHSCiXA9Nfc6c40gSMMJ5ZaBHkcm1PoA&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

But finally it is giving me the output city name undefined.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After get the lat and lng from position.coords, you may want to use geocoder to the get the city name. Check the code below

```
function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder
        .geocode(
                {
                    'latLng' : latlng
                },
                function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[1]) {

                            var arrAddress = results;
                            console.log(results);
                            // iterate through address_component array
                            $
                                    .each(
                                            arrAddress,
                                            function(i, address_component) {

                                                if (address_component.types[0] == "locality") {
                                                    console.log("City: "
                                                                    + address_component.address_components[0].long_name);
                                                    itemLocality = address_component.address_components[0].long_name;
                                                }
                                            });

                        } else {
                            alert("No results found");
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                    }
                });
```

}

Comment: @ Hammer : I have tested this its working and it is fetching the city name only.Here my requirement is  display the user's current place name inside that city.

Answer (score 0):

Although there may be a lot of examples found on google which contain `coords.locality` this property isn't documented somewhere(at least not in the [Geolocation-API](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#coordinates))

You'll need to run geocoding to get details like a city-name.